# ETag or hash in resources URL eg. js, css, image

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, browser-cache

I want to make sure resources in web application (css, js, and images) will be refreshed every time I change them leaving the same name of the resource (so that I dont need to change references in html to it). So I guess there are at least two obvious solutions:

1. Include ETAG in the response header
2. Include Hash in Url (ie /css/{hash}/style.css)

I liked second idea better, because maybe some older proxies or browser would ignore etag - is that right ? But it is bit more difficult to put hashes into url of images in css. So finally I guess I will go with the first option for images, and both the first and the second for css and js.

What are your thougts ? Would first just be enough, and every fairly modern software will request refresh of the resource if it will change.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the second, you could use a Apache Rewrite Rule to accomplish that. I assume you could hash the date modified/created of the file with whatever programming language you are using.

.htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^css/[^/]+/style.css$  css/style.css  [L]

Comment: Apache ? htaccess ? this is asp.net and probably windows.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience an etag is usually respected by browsers/proxies. However I've generally found that I've needed to set the last modified also. Also make sure that you have the etag formed correctly as some browsers are picky about that.